# Proving edge connectivity

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a $5$-regular graph with $\kappa(G) = 2$. Prove that $\lambda(G) \leq 4$.

As part of my revision for a graph theory I'm doing through some provided questions and answers, however the answer to the above wasn't provided.

I know that a $5$-regular graph contains vertices all with degree $5$.

So using Whitney's theorem we have: $\kappa(G) = 2 \leq \lambda(G) \leq 4 \leq \Delta(G) = 5$.

I'm just not really sure how to approach proving that Lambda is less than $5$.

If every vertex $v$ has degree $5$ and $\kappa(G) = 2$ then there must be $2$ internally disjoint paths between any $u$ and $v$ in the graph.

because of these two internally disjoint paths, the edges of $u$ must be split between these two paths, as such one path would have $2$ edges and another $3$ edges. This would be the same as $v$, which would at most have $2$ edges from one path and $3$ from the other.

This means that to destroy the connectivity of the graph, you could cut the two edges from $u$ and the two edges to $v$. If one or both of the paths have only $1$ edge, then the number of edges to cut will always be $\leq 4$.

Is this a sufficent proof? Is there anyway of making it simpler/neater?

Thanks

Comment: What are Kappa, Lambda and Delta?

Comment: Sorry - I actually thought about putting the definitions in but forgot! Kappa is the smallest k for which G has a k-cut. Lambda is the smallest k for which G has a k-edge cut. Delta is the smallest degree in G.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your argument quite works.  In particular, you can't really conclude anything about the lengths of your paths.  Here's a sketch of a proof using [Menger's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger%27s_theorem).  By way of contradiction, assume that the edge-connectivity of $G$ is 5. Let $u, v \in V(G)$.  By the edge-version of Menger's theorem, there are 5 edge-disjoint paths between $u$ and $v$.  Since, $G$ is 5-regular, no three of these paths can intersect at a common vertex (other than $u$ or $v$).  It is thus easy to construct 3 vertex-disjoint paths between $u$ and $v$.  By the vertex-version of Menger's theorem, $G$ is 3-connected, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Or, similarly but maybe a little more simply: let {u,v} be a two-vertex cut, and let x and y be vertices on opposite sides of the cut. If G were 5-edge-connected then there would be five edge-disjoint paths from x to y, each of which passes through u or v (or both); therefore, by the pigeonhole principle, at least three of the paths would have to go through one of the two vertices u and v, an impossibility.